# Google Storage JSON API NullPointException While Doing Object Downloading

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When I try to download a Storage object by using following codes I encountered a NullPointException:

```
    Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get(BUCKET_LOG, entity);
    getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);//directly download, which is recommended for non AppEngine Apps.
```

The stack trace is:
        `at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:186)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:553)
    at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(Storage.java:4606)
    at com.alibaba.intl.google.adwords.util.GoogleStorageUtil.downloadStorageObject(GoogleStorageUtil.java:149)`

So I took a look at line 186 of *MediaHttpDownloader* and found this:

```
    mediaContentLength = response.getHeaders().getContentLength();
```

Well, here is the problem, method ***getContentLength*** might return `null` value, while the type of variable `mediaContentLength` is **long**, but not **Long**.

A piece of the snapshot for class **HttpHeaders**:

```
   public final Long getContentLength() {
       return getFirstHeaderValue(contentLength);
   }

   /**Returns the first header value based on the given internal list value.*/
   private <T> T getFirstHeaderValue(List<T> internalValue) {
       return internalValue == null ? null : internalValue.get(0);
   }
```

I am using Java Library for AdWords API V201402.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Does it still happen if you remove the call to setDirectDownloadEnabled()?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Brandon. After I change to setDirectDownloadEnabled(false), the error gone away. So I guess this is a bug with direct download, it should be fine if we download media in trunks. But since direct-download is the recommended way for non-AppEngine Apps, I hope there will be a fix on this problem. Thanks again.